# NSUserDefaults - storing basic settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a flipView application. On the FlipView I keep settings for the MainView and would like to use NSUserDefaults to store 2 integers for the MainView. I will use those integers in the main application. Is there some basic code that can implement what I'm trying to do?

I'd like to store the information on the FlipView (if changed) and have a default setting when the program is first run in the MainView.

Also, will I need to `release` the NSUserDefaults object once I'm finished using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the integer with 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"theKey"] and retrive it with [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefautls] integerForKey:@"theKey"].  That's really all you need to handle an integer with user defaults.

You don't release the NSUserDefaults object.  It's a singleton, so only one will be created for the life of your app.  You also don't own it which means you wouldn't be releasing it.

Comment: marking this as the answer because I actually started with this code.

Answer (score 2):

check out below code, I had wrapped and make easy for you,

you can use below codes by:
import "Settings.h" in any code where you want to use, (maybe AppDelegate.m) in your case. then

to set value, use

```
[Settings setSetting:@"AUTOLOGIN" value:@"1"];
[Settings setSetting:@"OTHERPROPERTY" value:@"100"];
```

and remember that, store pointer datatype only,

to get setting value:

```
[Settings getSetting:@"AUTOLOGIN"];
```

here below there are two files, Setting.h and Setting.m , make those

header file is :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>    
@interface Settings : NSObject {

}
+(id) getSetting:(NSString *)key;
+(void) setSetting:(NSString *)key value:(id)v;
@end
```

- and implementation file is

```
#import "Settings.h"
@implementation GCCSettings
static NSMutableDictionary *settings = nil;

+(id) getSetting:(NSString *)key{
    if(settings == nil){
        settings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"settings"]
                    ];
    }
    return [settings objectForKey:key];
}

+(void) setSetting:(NSString *)key value:(id)v{
    [settings setValue:v forKey:key];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:settings forKey:@"settings"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
@end
```

and finally don't release any objects, which you had not allocated using(new, init, retain etc).